# I would like to create a rating system in java with GUI

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I works for a project and I would like to create a rating system.
I would like when I press on the 5th star all the stars become red, when I pres on 4th star; 1st start, 2nd star and 3rd star become red  and so on. I would be glad if you can give me some advises. Thank You!

Here is my code:

```
public class Rating {

private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

private JLabel inputLabel1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Rating();
}

public Rating() {
    JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Rating");
    inputLabel1 = new JLabel("Rate: ");

    Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon("star-icon.png");
    Icon icon2 = new ImageIcon("star-3-icon.png");

    JButton button1 = new JButton(icon1);
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    button1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button1.setDisabledIcon(icon1);
    button1.setPressedIcon(icon2);
    button1.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
    button1.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    button1.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
    button1.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon2);

    JButton button2 = new JButton(icon1);
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button2.setDisabledIcon(icon1);
    button2.setPressedIcon(icon2);
    button2.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
    button2.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    button2.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
    button2.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon2);

    JButton button3 = new JButton(icon1);
    button3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button3.setDisabledIcon(icon1);
    button3.setPressedIcon(icon2);
    button3.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    button3.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    button3.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
    button3.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon2);

    JButton button4 = new JButton(icon1);
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    button4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button4.setDisabledIcon(icon1);
    button4.setPressedIcon(icon2);
    button4.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
    button4.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    button4.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
    button4.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon2);

    JButton button5 = new JButton(icon1);
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    button5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button5.setDisabledIcon(icon1);
    button5.setPressedIcon(icon2);
    button5.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
    button5.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    button5.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
    button5.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon2);

    JButton button6 = new JButton("Subscribe");
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 35));

    final JTextArea display = new JTextArea(5, 25);

    JButton button7 = new JButton("Clear");
    button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 35));

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    f2.add(panel2);
    f2.setVisible(true);
    f2.setSize(500, 550);
    f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel2.add(inputLabel1);
    panel2.add(button1);
    panel2.add(button2);
    panel2.add(button3);
    panel2.add(button4);
    panel2.add(button5);
    panel2.add(button6);
    panel2.add(button7);
    panel2.add(display);

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String b1 = "1";
            results.add(b1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
    });
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String b2 = "2";
            results.add(b2);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
    });
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String b3 = "3";
            results.add(b3);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
    });
    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String b4 = "4";
            results.add(b4);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
    });
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String b5 = "5";
            results.add(b5);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
    });

    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = display.getText().toString();
            results.add(s);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {

                sb.append(string);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            display.setText(sb.toString());
            results.clear();

        }
    });

    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            results.clear();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String string : results) {
                sb.append(string);
            }

            display.setText(null);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Here's my advice:  break up your project into smaller concrete requirements, and then if you must ask questions here, ask concrete questions

Comment: Elena set switched for all the "stars" and turn them off or on depending on what you want...or is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: First off, learn about [`for` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 2):

To a `List<JToggleButton>` and a `JPanel` having the default `FlowLayout`, add five instances of `JToggleButton`. Use a suitable Unicode glyph for the star, e.g. [★ \u2605](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm), as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons). In your common `ItemListener`, `setForground()` to red or back for each element of the `List` as indicated by the received `ItemEvent` type in `getStateChange()`.

Answer (score 0):

For those all 5 buttons, you have very similar actions.

You can make your code neat by putting those actions into a method

```
public void buttonClicked(Button but)
```

Then pass your buttons to this method as:

```
buttonClicked(button1);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you would like to developp 
that Rating System for a User Feedback System, probably used in an mobile device, please beware of the Company Lodsys that has a Patent on that. See Info for angry birds Company  which was sued for their Feedback System.
See http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/lodsys-targets-angry-birds-maker-rovio-for-infringing-in-app-purchase-patent-20110725/
Please Note that Apple bought a license from them, but Independent lawyers say that this license does not include Apps  developped by other than Apple.

Comment: Tens of thousands of feedback systems exist in the world.  I'm not entirely convinced that a company has a patent on them.  Besides, this is something that's mathematically solvable.

Comment: @Makoto i updated, read and Research for yourself. However that seems to be related "only" for the US sw market

Comment: Dubious legal proceedings are better suited to being a comment.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson comments are limited in space. but unfortunately its not dubious, they have simply the patent on that. as long nobody has won the law suit against them, and as long the patent is valid in US, this information is much more important than how to draw 5 stars.

Comment: *"unfortunately its not dubious, they have simply the patent on that."*  It is the patent that is dubious.  The legalities inherit their dubious nature from that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have read the patent, you could read that too, it is not dubious, its a well written, easy understandable patent. But you might think that Software Patent at all does not make sense, but this you have to discuss with US Government. The dubious part is the Company Lodsys, which bought that patent only to sue other people. While usually patents are to protect company reasearch investments